# libvirt: Conflicting DNS updates from dnsmasq (DHCP) when having multiple interfaces

Tags: networking, dns, libvirt

For my guests I provide three networks, `vtunnel0`, `vlocal0` and a bridge to the physical NIC of the server:

```
<interface type='network'>
  <mac address='30:00:7b:6b:bb:10'/>
  <source network='vtunnel0'/>
  <model type='e1000'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x10' slot='0x01' function='0x0'/>
</interface>

<interface type='network'>
  <mac address='40:00:7b:6b:bb:10'/>
  <source network='vlocal0'/>
  <model type='e1000'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x10' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
</interface>

<interface type='direct'>
  <mac address='50:00:7b:6b:bb:10'/>
  <source dev='enp4s0' mode='bridge'/>
  <model type='e1000'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x10' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

The configuration of `vtunnel0` is as follows:

```
<network>
  <name>vtunnel0</name>
  <uuid>b417a4a0-7bf8-4f20-9a04-72ac8a6d6afa</uuid>
  <forward mode='route'/>
  <bridge name='vtunnel0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='3e:81:59:5d:b7:fe'/>
  <ip address='203.0.113.2' netmask='255.255.255.192'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='203.0.113.10' end='203.0.113.62'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

And for `vlocal0` as follows:

```
<network>
  <name>vlocal0</name>
  <uuid>1bbbe818-cbab-443d-9637-ee3e178e2c2b</uuid>
  <bridge name='vlocal0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='3c:3f:8a:c5:4b:c4'/>
  <ip address='10.8.17.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='10.8.17.6' end='10.8.17.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

My problem now is, that the `/etc/resolv.conf` of the guest is updated all few minutes with different contents. Sometimes it contains `nameserver 203.0.113.2`, sometimes `nameserver 10.8.17.1` and sometimes the two nameservers of the physical NIC.

So it seems that `libvirt` or `dnsmasq` is somewhat not aware that there are three networks. All three networks are configured by DHCP.

Is this a normal behaviour? How can I ensure that for instance the DNS servers are only retrieved from `vtunnel0` or the physical NIC? I want to fix it from the *host*, not the guest side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/etc/resolvconf/interface-order` to prioritize using the nameservers from a specific interface over others

Otherwise, you can add `supersede domain-name-servers "1.2.3.4","5.6.7.8";` entries to your `dhclient.conf` for each interface to ignore whatever DNS servers they're getting from DHCP. Or you can comment out `domain-name-servers` from the `request` list

Comment: But this is on the guest side, right? I want to fix it on the hosts side.

Comment: It looks like the host side runs a separate instance of dnsmasq for each network by default, but you can set it globally instead like in the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/682744/247007